# How do I open a program in a Win32 Console without cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have little previous experience with Windows (for programming, anyway), but recognizing that Windows has an enormous market share, I am trying to support it in my programs (even though they are just for fun, I like to pretend they're big projects). I have written a tiny shell with minimal (and when I say minimal, I mean minimal) features.

I am trying to port it to Windows and would like to use it independently from cmd.exe in a Win32 Console window (meaning the shell part of cmd.exe isn't running at all, but the window used for it shows). I have already done most of the other porting stuff such as build system (CMake) and changing appropriate Unix syscalls to Windows ones in a #define. I have done a little research and found little on this topic, however. I know it is possible because I've seen it done with Bash. Visual Studio also used to do it when I ran a program in its GUI.

Reference article I got some of this info from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console

Note: What I mean is when you click on it and it opens it without running cmd in its own little console window. Or when you type it into cmd it opens in a separate window that isn't running cmd. I am assuming cmd.exe and the console window it runs in are two separate things, but if I am wrong, please let me know. :)

This question is inspired by https://askubuntu.com/questions/111144/are-terminal-and-shell-the-same and a similar question where I got that Wikipedia link. Someone said that the console window and the shell were separate. I was writing my own shell so I started to wonder how to make mine independent of the default one.

Comment: You just start it. Programs have a bit in the header saying if they are graphical (ie non console) or console. To make a program - in .NET the switches are `/t:winexe` and `/t:exe` (console). CMD.exe and the console are different things. CMD is a console program, like Ipconfig. Programs share the console too - if CMD starts a console program and that program starts another console program, all three are in the console.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Win32 Console and cmd.exe are two different things. Windows automatically opens a console window when a program that needs one is started. It decides whether do to so by switches hard-wired into the executable. This window will be running said program. If the program that started the process is running in a console window, the two programs will share that console window.

As Noodles said, it really is that simple. You just start it. Double-clicking on it will do it. The CreateProcess() function with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE passed to it will do it. Running the program from cmd.exe with

```
start <command>
```

will do it.

There is also a family of functions in the Windows API, called FreeConsole() and AllocConsole() that will free a program from its current console and create a new console for it, respectively.

Reference link (given by Noodles): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx